# Django displaying selected items from multiple select in template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a multiple select in a ModelForm. When the page reloads with an error I want the currently **selected** items to be displayed.

## view.html

```
error: {{ form.recipients.errors }}<br/>
currently selected: <br/>
{% for recipient in form.recipients %} <!--I want some type of loop through only the selected items in my recipients -->
    {{ recipient }}<br/>
{% endfor %}
{{ form.recipients }}
```

Comment: What do you mean "Doesn't work"?

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to express what kind of mechanism I wanted. It doesn't work because it is not valid code. I'll edit it to try and express my point more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to loop the value of the field, not the field itself:

```
{% for recipient in form.recipients.value %}
    {{ recipient }}
{% endfor %}
```